# How can I make this more efficient? - Multiple jQuery Toggles

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a handful of images working as jQuery toggle switches - Showing or hiding an element on a click event.

The code below mostly works as intended, but I'm fairly certain I'm using a lot of unnecessary stuff to make it happen.  Any suggestions on streamlining?

Also, any suggestions on closing (toggle to hide) any visible elements that had already been toggled to visible?  As it works now, if the user clicks on the first image and then the second image, it stacks the newly visible elements on top of each other.  Ideally, I'd like to close (hide) the element from the first toggle when the second toggle is clicked and/or close any open elements on a scroll event.

The code below is abridged.  There's actually 10+ toggles which can get a little unwieldy if the user has opened a bunch of them.

**EDIT -** Based on the answers below, I used common classes to tighten up the jQuery.  The solution is also closing(hiding) any other open(visible) elements when the next toggle is clicked, but only within that toggle's parent.  Since there are multiple UL's broken up between multiple parent div's, clicking to close wihtin "column2" will close any visible elements within "column2", but not within another column (ie: an open/visible element from column1)

**UPDATED CODE:**

```js
 $(".show-wine").click(function(){
// Hide all wines except for the one that was clicked
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".wine-text").hide();
// Show or hide the one that was clicked
    $(".wine-text", $(this).parent()).toggle();
});
 $(".hide-wine").click(function(){
    $('.wine-text').hide(); // Hide all wines
});
```

```css
.wine-text {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:3em;
  left:1.5em;
  width:35em;
  padding:1em;
  height:auto;
  min-height:30em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:4px;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:left;
}
.wine-tiles li img:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:.7;
}
.wine-tiles li img .unhide:hover .wine-text {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="column1">  
  <ul class="wine-tiles">         
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#1</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title1</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#2</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title2</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#3</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title3</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="column2">
  <ul class="wine-tiles">         
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#4</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title4</h2>
    </li>
  <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#5</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title5</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#6</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title6</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```js
$("#show-wine").click(function(){  
  $(".wine-text").toggle();
});
$("#show-wine2").click(function(){  
  $(".wine-text2").toggle();
});
$("#show-wine3").click(function(){ 
  $(".wine-text3").toggle();
});
```

```css
.wine-text, .wine-text2, .wine-text3, .wine-text4, .wine-text5, .wine-text6, .wine-text7, .wine-text8, .wine-text9 {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:3em;
  left:1.5em;
  width:35em;
  padding:1em;
  height:auto;
  min-height:30em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:4px;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:left;
}
.wine-tiles li img:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:.7;
}
.wine-tiles li img .unhide:hover .wine-text {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="column1">  
  <ul class="wine-tiles">         
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" id="show-wine" class="unhide bounce" alt="Img 1"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#1</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button id="hide-wine" class="button">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" id="show-wine2" class="unhide bounce" alt="Img 2"/>         
      <span class="wine-text2">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#2</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button id="hide-wine" class="button">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" id="show-wine3" class="unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text3">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#3</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button id="hide-wine" class="button">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="column2">
  <ul class="wine-tiles">         
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" id="show-wine" class="unhide bounce" alt="Img 1"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
      <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#4</span><br>
      <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
      <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
      <br/><br/>
      <button id="hide-wine" class="button">Close</button>
    </span> 
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" id="show-wine2" class="unhide bounce" alt="Img 2"/>         
    <span class="wine-text2">
      <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#5</span><br>
      <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
      <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
      <br/><br/>
      <button id="hide-wine" class="button">Close</button>
    </span> 
    <h2>Title</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" id="show-wine3" class="unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text3">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#6</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button id="hide-wine" class="button">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why did you close `<h2>` tags with `</p>`?

Comment: @Oriol I was cutting out a bunch of my actual code to make it cleaner for Stack and missed the edit.

Comment: @PrestonS I have rolled back your edit because I already added the interactive snippet in a previous edit, and because your snippet doesn't work because the images are not displayed (I added `alt` attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficiënt way (there are multiple ways to do it ofcourse), but this would be one of them:

http://jsfiddle.net/zah9a7xp/2/

By selecting the images by class and using it's parent you can get javascript code like this:

```
$(".show-wine").click(function(){
    var $target = $(".wine-text", $(this).parent());
    // Hide all wines except for the one that was clicked
    $('.wine-text').not($target).hide();
    // Show or hide the one that was clicked
    $target.toggle();
});
$(".hide-wine").click(function(){
    $('.wine-text').hide(); // Hide all wines
});
```

Comment: This makes sense and I genuinely appreciate the help. How can I go up one more parent? In my actual implementation, I'm running off a skelJS skeleton which has 3 different columns (parents) for each group of image toggles. This means that this solution works for each column/parent, but not across columns if that makes sense. I included an edited copy of the code in my original text.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think this'll fix your problem.

Comment: Awesome!!!!!  Thank you so much for your help and patience.  I'm not great with the correct terminology, so it can be difficult to explain my question in a way that makes sense to someone besides me =).  This works perfectly and I believe I understand why.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Simply give a common class to the element that trigger the toggle and a common class on the toggled element. Then, for your specific case, you could use that :

```
$(".show-wine").click(function(){  
    var $target = $(this).next('.wine-text').toggle();
    $('.wine-text').not($target).hide()
});
```

That will not work if you slightly change you DOM. For a more general case, you'd need to target the common parent first :

```
$(".show-wine").click(function(){  
    var $target = $(this).closest('li').find('.wine-text').toggle();
    $('.wine-text').not($target).hide()
});
```

---

```js
$(".show-wine").click(function(){  
    var $target = $(this).closest('li').find('.wine-text').toggle();
    $('.wine-text').not($target).hide()
});
```

```css
.wine-text {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:3em;
  left:1.5em;
  width:35em;
  padding:1em;
  height:auto;
  min-height:30em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:4px;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:left;
}
.wine-tiles li img:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:.7;
}
.wine-tiles li img .unhide:hover .wine-text {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="column1">  
  <ul class="wine-tiles">         
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#1</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title1</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#2</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title2</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#3</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title3</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="column2">
  <ul class="wine-tiles">         
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#4</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title4</h2>
    </li>
  <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#5</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title5</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/labels/image.jpg" class="show-wine unhide bounce" alt="Img 3"/>         
      <span class="wine-text">
        <span class="wine-text-title centered">Wine#6</span><br>
        <span class="wine-text-winery centered">Big White House</span><br><br>
        <span class="wine-text-copy">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="button hide-wine">Close</button>
      </span> 
      <h2>Title6</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Both examples you give here will not close any previously opened wine-text.

Comment: @vrijdenker was only answer his main question, which was *"How can I make this more efficient?"* Well, added the closing thingy

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon -  The common class solution was my initial question.  I knew it had to be simple but wasn't sure how to do it.  Thanks.  Any suggestions on targeting the toggle on the parent div as I referenced below vrijdenker's solution?  I updated the HTML accordingly.

Comment: @sforcash not sure to fully understand your question. That code should hide everything except the one clicked.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - I updated my original post to try to clarify.  The goal now is to close any visible .wine-text elements when the user clicks on a different toggle to avoid having multiple visible .wine-text containers open at once.  vrijdenker's solution didn't take into account that there were multiple parent divs (My HTML wasn't updated at the time)

Comment: @sforcash and the current code doesn't work as intended?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Using the updated snippet at the top, if you start by clicking under "Title6" and then scroll up to "Title1", it won't close Title6 - I believe because they are in different parent divs.  I'm sure I'm using the wrong term, but I believe I need to udpate the jQuery to go up an extra parent, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @sforcash in your snippet, yes the sixth one doesn't go away. But in my snippet, with my code, it does... Not sure to understand your problem.